# Read binary file into array in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, file-read

I've got a file named `trace.dat` that contains 4 byte integers. Can anybody tell me how to open and read the file, and store each integer in an array called `arr` (in MIPS)? Thanks!

So far I have this:

```
li $v0, 13
la $a0, file    #file contains the file name
li $a1, 0
li $a2, 0
syscall
add $s0, $v0, $0
```

Comment: Use [the file I/O syscalls](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) that SPIM/MARS provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have merely opens the file, and does not read it. In order to actually read the contents of a file you've opened into a buffer, you need to use syscall number 14, like this :

```
li $v0, 14
move $a0, $s0
la $a1, arr
li $a2, 32
syscall
bltz $v0, error
```

This code assumes that `$s0` contains the file descriptor of the opened file, which you already have in there due to `add $s0, $v0, $0`. It also assumes that the size of `arr` is 32 bytes.

If your file is larger than 32 bytes, you can write a loop that runs until syscall 14 returns 0 or a value smaller than the size of the buffer. Then, you can process the data read from the file inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the ``32`` in your line 4, by ``4096``, and it totally worked. My file was 4096 bytes long.